# How to send a yolo detected objects to mail

Tags: python, yolo, darknet

How to send the detected objects via mail.
for ex:If an knife is detected i want the captured image or messge that the knife has been detected.

Comment: YOLO is a deep learning model for object detection, it does its part when it detects a *knife*. Now, you need to search for how to send email via python and how to attach an image inside it. Now, if YOLO detects anything like *knife*, then send the email.

Comment: Glad I could help, Good luck :)